# mysql query text replace issue

Tags: mysql, text, joomla

I have a joomla database with '`jos_content`' table containing the details about the articles.

In that table, the column '`attribs`' is of `TEXT` datatype, which contains data about the article properties, like:

```
show_pdf_icon=0
show_print_icon=0
show_email_icon=0
```

I am trying to modify the property 'show_print_icon' so that it will have 1, like this:

```
show_pdf_icon=0
show_print_icon=1
show_email_icon=0
```

For this, i have written a query that replaces the 'show_print_icon=0' to 'show_print_icon=1' in the column.

```
UPDATE jos_content set attribs=replace("attribs", "%print_icon=0\nshow_email%",
"%print_icon=1\nshow_email%") where attribs like '%print_icon=0\nshow_email%';
```

For some reason, after executing this query, i got the column values as empty. 
I could not understand where did i go wrong. What could be the problem with query?

Answer (score 1):

One way is :

```
$sql = "Select attribs from jos_content";
$db = JFactory::getDBO():
$db->setQuery($sql):
$contents = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($contents as $content){
   $attribs = $content->attribs;
   $attribs = explode("\n", $attribs);
   if(!$attribs['show_print_icon']){
      $attribs['show_print_icon'] = 1;
      $content->attribs = implode("\n", $attribs);
   // run the update query here for each content
   }      
}
```

I'll let you know other way, using Com Content Model

Answer (score 0):

Check the newline character. It may not be \n, it could be also \r\n or just \r, so you can't reliably match on this rule.

Also, why do you need the text surroundig? It just makes your login more complex than it has to be. You will have to be sure to keep consistent data and not have the variables there in another order for example.

I don't know what is your database structure there, but try to match on exactly what you need to change. If it's not possible now, than try to change your logic so you make it possible